# Ursina engine texture mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine

So the problem I'm facing is that I cannot figure out how to apply textures to a model in a way that texture would be different on each side. For example I wanted to create Minecraft like grass blocks with bottom being brown, sides - green and brown and top - green. I already searched up this issue and found that it is possible to use UVs but I cannot figure out how. I already tried creating UV map in Blender then exported it and put it both as a texture and model and other combinations however it did not change the model so I let it be built-in 'cube' and changed just texture but it literally just put the UV's `.png` file on all sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uvs are in model definition not texture.

make sure that you have only one uv in blender and [unwraped model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k) (default cube is not unwraped).

when you import from blender to ursina it should import uvs as well (around line 224 [here](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/mesh_importer.py))

then you should apply the texture to mesh

Comment: thanks for help, I finally understood. So basically you create `.blend` file and the filename is model's name and the texture is a textured uv image however there is a slight problem where some parts of the model dont render properly. So what happens is that most of it gets rendered except some part from the viewing angle however if I approach the entity from a different angle that part is now rendered but the one I am viewing the model from is not. any suggestions?

Comment: nevermind, I fixed that issue it was just that mesh was not completed there were holes

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use Microsoft's `3D Builder` to build models and `Paint 3D` to paint it. Re-import it to `3D Builder` to save as a `.obj` with a `.mtl` file and a  `.png` texture map. It works for Ursina as I've tried.